# Display Spinner with Value in AlertDialog

Tags: android

Goal:
Display the value for the spinner in relation to AlertDialog

Problem:
What code am I missing in order for the spinner to be working with the value?

Info:
*I'm newbie in Android.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alertFormElements2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="alertFormElements2"
            android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

form_elements2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="131dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.jfdimarzio.t1;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



    public void alertFormElements2(View vdf) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_elements2,null, false);

        // the alert dialog
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setView(formElementsView)
                .setTitle("Form Elements")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(11)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        String[] vvalue = new String[]{
                                "7",
                                "3",
                                "6",
                                "3",
                                "8",
                                "9",
                                "15",
                                "11",
                                "57"
                        };

                        Spinner _spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, vvalue);
                        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
                        _spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }

                }).show();
    } // alertFormElements

} // Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're not actually setting the spinner's values until the user clicks your ok button, at which point you immediately dismiss the dialog.  You'll need to set the spinner up before then.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_elements2,null, false);

    String[] vvalue = new String[]{
            "7",
            "3",
            "6",
            "3",
            "8",
            "9",
            "15",
            "11",
            "57"
    };

    // Set up spinner BEFORE launching dialog
    final Spinner _spinner = formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, vvalue);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    _spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    // the alert dialog
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setView(formElementsView)
            .setTitle("Form Elements")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @TargetApi(11)
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    SpinnerDialogItemSelected(_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
```

And then create a method for your dialog to call which lets you handle the result

```
private void SpinnerDialogItemSelected(String value){
    // Do your thing here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!